# Advice multiple insert Cakephp 1 model

Tags: cakephp

I was wondering if there is another way more "cakephp like" to insert the user_id in multiple insert on the same Table. Example of what I do :

```
$user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        foreach ($this->request->data['Post'] as $key => $value) {
            if (is_int($key)) {
                $this->request->data['Post'][$key]['user_id'] = $user_id;
            }
            unset($key);
            unset($value);
        }
        debug($this->data['Post']);
        die();
        $this->Post->saveAll($this->data['Post']);
    }
```

I don't use input hidden value user_id for serurity reason.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$result = Set::insert($this->request->data, 'Post.{n}.user_id', array('user_id' => $user_id));
```

Comment: If you are using the Security component you can use hidden inputs freely

Comment: Yes but I do not think it's practical to disabledFields  each field :/ when I'm using javascript

Answer (score 0):

If my memory recalls me correctly, your data needs to look like the following and call saveAll on user model

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => {you_user_id}
        )
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [field] => blah
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [field] => blah
                )
        )
)
```

In other words:

```
$this->request->data['User'] = array('id' => $this->Auth->user('id'));
$this->Post->User->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing, I mean something like that :
    array(
 'Post' => array(
  (int) 1 => array(
   'title' => 'gdfgdf',
   'user_id' => '5'
  ),
  (int) 2 => array(
   'title' => 'sdfgd',
   'user_id' => '5'
  )
 )
)